# CSS Hover over an image to make a sub menu appear

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I'm trying to make it so that I can use a menu like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/BEhvQ/)

To be fair I barely understood this and I was informed that you can use a style with the hover function.

Here's what I tried with my code:

```
<center>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="audiorageHome.aspx"><img src="images/audiorageGIFtype/audiorageBanner.gif" alt="Welcome to AudioRage!"/></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="audiorageHome.aspx"><img src="images/audiorageGIFtype/audiorageButtonHome.gif" alt="Home"/></a>
            <img class="showHim" src="images/audiorageGIFtype/audiorageButtonStore.gif" alt="Store" />
            <a href="audiorageAbout.aspx"><img src="images/audiorageGIFtype/audiorageButtonAbout.gif" alt="About"/></a>
            <a href="audiorageCart.aspx"><img src="images/audiorageGIFtype/audiorageButtonCart.gif" alt="Cart"/></a>
        </li>                    
    </ul>
</center>
<br />
<center>
    <div class="showMe">I want this to show!!</div>
</center>
```

Here's the CSS

```
.showMe
{ 
display: none;
}
.showHim:hover .showMe
{
display: block;
}
```

Here's a pre-made link of the code to [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4DvEZ/1/)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You can read some FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq. And please consider to mark helpful answer as right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work because your `display:block` rule is looking for `.showHim` that is being hovers with the child of `.showMe`. You can do it a couple of ways.

---

Targeting a hidden **child**: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/gYQAB/)

**CSS**

```
.hoverme:hover .showMe {
    display: block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<span class="hoverme">
    <img class="showHim" src="images/audiorageGIFtype/audiorageButtonStore.gif" alt="Store" />
    <span class="showMe">I want this to show!!</span>
</span>
```

---

Or targeting a **sibling** [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/ys7Gb/)

**CSS**

.showHim:hover + .showMe {
    display: block;
}

**HTML**

```
<img class="showHim" src="images/audiorageGIFtype/audiorageButtonStore.gif" alt="Store" />
<span class="showMe">I want this to show!!</span>
```

---

The typical menu is structured like this which makes it easy to target the hidden item. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/TxmTJ/)

**HTML**

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        Some menu item
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li>Sub menu item</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    ...
 </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.submenu {
    display:none;
}
.menu > li:hover .submenu {
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some jQuery here to make if work:

```
    $(".showHim").hover(
      function () {
        $('.showMe').css("display","block");
      },
      function () {
        $('.showMe').css("display","none");
      }
    );
   });
```

[Here working example](http://jsfiddle.net/4DvEZ/2/)

Answer (score 0):

for this you need to change your html structure

html code

```
<center>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="audiorageHome.aspx"><img src="images/audiorageGIFtype/audiorageBanner.gif" alt="Welcome to AudioRage!"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="audiorageHome.aspx"><img src="images/audiorageGIFtype/audiorageButtonHome.gif" alt="Home"/></a></li>
        <li class="showHim"><img src="images/audiorageGIFtype/audiorageButtonStore.gif" alt="Store" />
        <div class="showMe">I want this to show!!</div></li>
        <li><a href="audiorageAbout.aspx"><img src="images/audiorageGIFtype/audiorageButtonAbout.gif" alt="About"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="audiorageCart.aspx"><img src="images/audiorageGIFtype/audiorageButtonCart.gif" alt="Cart"/></a></li>                 
    </ul>
</center>
```

CSS Code

```
.showMe{ 
    display: none;
}
.showHim:hover .showMe{
    display: block;
}
```

[JsFiddle file](http://jsfiddle.net/8pdve/)